# Расспаристь "тег" игнорируя похожие

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В теле документа есть специальные теги в виде `{name}`, все бы хорошо, но есть конфликт, когда есть похожий тег `{{name}}`, где вместо одной фигурной скобки две. Как написать регулярное выражение, чтобы второй вариант игнорировался(. т.е работал только `{name}`.
Мои пробы:

```
preg_match_all('/\[^{]*{([ \w\-_0-9#.\+]+)\}[^}]*/u', $cont, $match);
```

Comment: [`{([^}]+)}(?=\h)`](https://regex101.com/r/uTNxzo/1)

Comment: @Node_pro `'~[^{]{([^}]+)}[^}]~'`

Comment: @Let's say Pie, что такое \h?

Comment: @Node_pro, можете заменить это на `\s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно не универсальное решение, но как начало пойдет, возможно додумаете сами:

```
$test = '1 {name1} 2 {{name2}} 3 {name3} 4';

preg_match_all('#[^{]{([^{]*)}#U', $test, $out);
var_dump($out[1]);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "name1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "name3"
}
```

Comment: Думаю тут без `U` можно обойтись)

Comment: @Let'ssayPie `U` позволяет игнорить некоторые случаи, например `1 {name1} }2`.

Comment: @Manitikyl, все хорошо, но если тег в начале строки, то тоже игнорируется, как это поправить?

Comment: @Node_pro ну чтоб не усложнять регулярку, можно в строку спереди пробел добавить `:)`

Comment: @Manitikyl, так не интересно ;-). Но я вроде бы поправил недуг с уровня php. А в есть возможность сделать класс в классе?   например `(<([^>]+)>)`

Comment: @Node_pro не совсем понял вопрос, но сделать можно все (нужно только желание)